# Smooth function between compact manifold and connected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions, compact-manifolds

I have this problem and I don't know how to proceed with it:

> Let $M$ be a compact manifold $N$ a connected manifold and $f\colon M \longrightarrow N$ a smooth function. If $f$ doesn't have critical points, then prove that $f$ is surjective.

What I know is that since $f$ doesn't have critical points, all the points in $N$ are regular. Since $M$ is compact, then $f(M)$ is compact too. Now, if $n\in N$ is a point such that $n\notin f(M)$, then I can define the function $g\colon M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $g$ defines the shortest length from $x\in M$ to $n$, I know that this function must have a maximum and a minimum, but from this the only thing I can infer is that there is an open neighborhood for $n$ in $N$. What can I do to finish the problem?

**EDIT:** $M$ and $N$ are of the same dimension.

Comment: You need them to both be of the same dimension. (Otherwise consider the inclusion of a point into $\mathbb{R}$). Then you will use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, they're of the same dimension.

Comment: But with the inverse function theorem I need the point to be in $f(M)$. If the point isn't there I can't use it, no?

Comment: As in Aloizio's answer, you only care about points you know a priori to be in the image. If you want a geometric consequence of this exercise, you can prove that any map from $S^n$ to $R^n$ must crease the sphere (i.e. have a critical point).

Comment: Actually, you don't need $M$ and $N$ to be the same dimension. If dim $M$ $<$ dim $N$, then every point of $M$ is a critical point. And if dim $M$ $>$ dim $N$, then $f$ is an open map.

Comment: You forgot to assume that $M$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is obviously closed, since it is compact. The image is open by the inverse function theorem. Since it is non-empty and $Y$ is connected, it is the whole space.

**EDIT:** As Jack Lee pointed out in the comments, the assumption of $\dim M= \dim N$ is unnecessary. You only need that $M$ is nonempty, since if $\dim M < \dim N$ every point is a critical point (contradicting the hypothesis), and if $\dim M > \dim N$, the local form of submersions (which is also a consequence of the inverse function theorem) tells us that $f$ is an open map, and the argument follows in the same way.

Comment: Thanks. That was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ has no critical points, then $F$ must be a submersion and therefore an open map. As $M$ is hausdorff, $F(N)$ is both, closed and open in M. By connectedness of $M$, $F(N)=M$ and so $F$ is surjective.